# Linux head and tail equivalent command in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In Linux, it's easy to get first few data from top or bottom with `head` and `tail` command.

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat db.txt 
| information_schema |
| database_name      |
| mysql              |
| opencart           |
| wordpress          |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
wolf@linux:~$
```

top 2

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat db.txt | head -2
| information_schema |
| database_name      |
wolf@linux:~$
```

Last 2

```
wolf@linux:~$ cat db.txt | tail -2
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
wolf@linux:~$
```

Is there any similar command in MySQL?

All databases

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| database_name      |
| mysql              |
| opencart           |
| wordpress          |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+

7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

Desired Output: Top 2 database

```
mysql> <mysql command here>
+--------------------+
|     Databases      |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| database_name      |
```

Desired Output: Last 2 database

```
mysql> <mysql command here>
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Its probably going to break at some point as you can't rely on ordering of result to an SQL query unless you specify a field to order on.

Comment: For the commandline mysql tool, see `pager`.  For your two examples:  `pager head -5` and `pager tail -4` would get those outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL there is no command that would resemble `head` or `tail`.

The easiest way would be to execute a mysql query on the shell using `mysql -e` and then piping the result to `head` or `tail`, e.g.

```
$ sudo mysql -e "SHOW DATABASES" --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -2
performance_schema
sys
```

If you want to do this from within the mysql shell you'd need to query the `information_schema` database like this:

```
mysql> (SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`SCHEMATA` 
ORDER BY `SCHEMA_NAME` DESC LIMIT 2) ORDER BY `SCHEMA_NAME`;
+--------------------+
| SCHEMA_NAME        |
+--------------------+
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

where you use `LIMIT` to restrict the result set to the number of desired rows.